# How to return a nested array to a String?

Tags: java, gson

I am getting result as an array of String arrays.

```
ArrayList<String[]> result = myObj.foo(parameters);
```

and I have to return this result to a webservice request get method so I have to convert it to String before returning.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(result);
return json;
```

The problem is I should get an array of 6 arrays. But when I check with Postman I only see below is returned:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@daeeada3,
    [Ljava.lang.String;@51fec4f,
```

As you see only the first 2 addresses of arrays are returned of my list of arrays. My question is is there a mistake I make when I return array of arrays by above code? Also can I use a different approach converting an array of arrays to a string instead of using gson?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not an array. So there is no “array of arrays” here. Further, an array does not have a dedicated `toString()` method, hence, an output like `[Ljava.lang.String;@daeeada3` is expected. `"[Ljava.lang.String;@daeeada3"` still a *string*, not an address. The hexadecimal number is the hash code. There is no address involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small test to replicate your scenario and converted JSON properly.

```
@Test
void verifyGSONConvertWhenArrayOfArrayString() {
    // Initialize a list of type DataObject

    String[] array = {"foo", "bar"};
    String[] array2 = {"foo2", "bar2"};
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(array);
    list.add(array2);

    // Convert the object to a JSON string
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    System.out.println(json);

}
```

I'm getting result like below.

[image]